# Explode в MySQL запросе

Tags: mysql

Как я понял, аналога Explode в MySQL нет. Но как быть с такими ситуациями? Есть набор материалов в базе данных, каждый из которых имеет строковой параметр с перечисленными значениями (`11,12,35`), и по этому параметру необходимо обеспечить поиск. Ну, вернее, по его части. Например, `11`.

Когда же дело доходит до поиска, например, по значению `1`, то, как и следовало ожидать, находятся все материалы, куда включено данное значение: `1`, `11`, `12`, `21`,... Как быть в такой ситуации?

Заводить отдельную таблицу со значениями параметров и затем третью, связывающую их "многие ко многим"? Но таких параметров много, причем, большинство из них ограничено парой десятков значений, а некоторые - и вообще, двумя-тремя, то есть, заводить +2 таблицы для каждого из таких параметров было бы неприятно. Хотя, возможно, это и правильное решение...

Пока вопрос решил записью в базу данных параметров, окруженных запятыми (`,1,2,3,`) - если в такой строке искать `,1,`, то проблем с другими значениями возникнуть не должно. Правда, этот вариант исключает возможность поиска по нескольким параметрам.

Comment: find_in_set чем не угодил?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

С подобными строками одна проблема - использование индексов для поиска невозможно. и любой поиск будет полностью перебирать всю таблицу. Вообще есть функция `find_in_set`, которая ищет значение в списке через запятую, но опять же полным перебором. или `concat(',',filed,',') like '%,1,%'`. Или вообще `concat(',',filed,',') regexp ',(1|15|23),'` для поиска любого из 3х перечисленных значений.

Отдельная таблица для быстрого поиска - наиболее правильное решение, т.к. наверняка в ней вот те значения `1, 11, 21` будут foreign key из другой таблицы, то на них уже будет построен индекс и при поиске `where field=1` будут отобраны только нужные записи и не будет полного перебора таблицы.

Единственный случай, когда отдельная таблица замедляет работу - это выборка всех значений для конкретной записи. Считать одну строку и сразу показать - конечно быстрее. При частых выборках возможно есть смысл внести избыточность и хранить обоими способами.