# Как при сохранении в базу данных id фильмов через запятую потом вывести их в формате таблицы?

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица "юзеры" и "фильмы", а так же общая таблица "просмотренные". В "просмотренных" в колонку id_фильма идет запись id фильма через запятую. Как потом например на странице юзера сделать вывод всех этих фильмов?

Comment: нормальными средствами никак. реляционные БД не предназначены для хранения чего либо через запятую. это нарушает 1ю нормальную форму. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0  необходимо нормализовать БД создав отдельную таблицу вида id-пользователя id-фильма (одного)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Explode в MySQL запросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/500319/explode-%d0%b2-mysql-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b5)

Comment: А если например не через запятую а через знак | то же самое будет?

Comment: разумеется. запятая в принципе чуть лучше всего остального, потому как find_in_set на нее заточен. но принципиальная невозможность работать с такой таблицей по индексу опускает производительность ниже плинтуса. А правильная таблица во первых даст большую производительность, во вторых облегчит добавление/удаление (потому что вы просто добавляете новую запись и вам не надо вытягивать всю строку и добавлять значение, про удаление из строки я вообще молчу. И кроме того в такую таблицу вы потом можете легко добавить поле для фиксации голосования за фильм, добавления в избранное или еще что

Comment: Думаю, можно получать строку с  id фильмов через запятую, перебирать её как массив, созданный с помощью explode, и делая запрос к БД в каждом цикле с выборкой по текущему id. Но конечно лучше воспользоваться советом Mike.