# Mysql выборка повторяющих значений

Tags: mysql

Имеются поля примерно такого рода

```
[tags] => мяч, стол, часовня
[tags] => угол, стол, поле
[tags] => карандаш, окно, поле
```

мне нужно вывести поля у которых есть хотябы одно совпадение (например слово "стол")

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/500319/  оно ?

Comment: немного не то что нужно

Comment: мне кажется, в принципе делать такую таблицу в бд - "не то, что нужно".

Comment: тогда сформулируйте вопрос как нибудь по другому, например [tags] это одно поле где значения через запятую  (если так, то чем не устраивает find_in_set или like) или это все таки "поля" (в множественном числе) как написано выше

Comment: как насчет этого? select * from table where tags like '%стол%'

Comment: пытаюсь сделать так SELECT tags FROM Message2003 GROUP BY tags HAVING count(*)>1 но выводит не то

Comment: like ищет по шаблону, я ведь изначально не знаю какие там значения