# Sql выборка в базе в одном столбце перечисленны id

Tags: mysql, sql

Нужно сделать выборку по одному столбцу в котором данные хранятся так

```
34,55,67,8
```

Нужно проверить, есть ли, к примеру, 55 или 55 и 67, оператор `like` не подходит, если 1 то он выбирает и 11, и 14, и т. д.

Пока сделал так

```
select * from table where (rubrik_id LIKE 7%) or (rubric_id LIKE %,7%)
```

Если есть что поумнее, жду.

Comment: Если нужно, то делайте. Что вы от нас хотите не понятно.

Comment: Дополните вопрос исходными данными и примерами неудачных попыток

Comment: Следует обрамить запятыми и значение поля, и строку поиска. Хотя гораздо умнее нормализовать этот кошмар.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Explode в MySQL запросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/500319/explode-%d0%b2-mysql-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b5)

Comment: Если база ваша - то никогда не храните так данные, лучше переделайте это сейчас, иначе потом проблемы будут только множиться. Если же база не ваша, но вам нужно делать к ней запросы, то я вам просто сочувствую.